# Selenium webdriver scripts not running on chrome in different machine

Tags: java, macos, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to run the webdriver scripts in chrome on a different MAC machine. I am running the jar passing browser as parameter from command line, It works fine on my machine. But throwing  the below error when run on another machine:

```
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.5', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
Cause : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.5', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

I am initializing the driver this way

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Projlibrary/chromedriver"); 

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Projlibrary/chromedriver");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Can anybody suggest what could be the cause?

Comment: May be the version of the chrome may differ from both machines.Make the chrome version similar to the machine which you have worked earlier

Comment: Same issue even after updating the chrome version

Comment: I too faced the same problem with firefox . In my case my selinium jar which i have, Supports only for firefox 28,One day my firefox got updated to 30 and the respective jar is not supporting to the verison.So I downloaded the updated selinium jar(supports version 30) and replaced with old jar .After that everything started working fine....  Check my process may help you...